Approximation property for Banach spaces $\ell^p(I)$ when $I$ is an uncountable set
A Banach space $(X,\| \cdot \|)$ for which all finite rank operators $T: X \rightarrow X$ are (norm) dense in the compact operators is said to have the approximation property (AP).
For $1\leq p < \infty$ and a non-empty set $I$, if we define $\ell^p(I):=\{f: I \rightarrow \Bbb R| \sum_{i\in I}|f(i)|^p<\infty\}$ equipped with the norm defined by $$\|f\|:= \big(\sum_{i\in I}|f(i)|^p\Big)^{1\over p},$$ then it is shown that when $I$ is assumed a countable set, all of such spaces have the AP property. Is it also true when $I$ is assumed uncountable?

It takes essentially no additional effort to show the following more general result.

Let $X$ be a Banach space, $I$ a non-empty set and $p\in [1, \infty )$. Then every compact operator $T:X\to \ell^{p}(I)$ can be approximated in the operator norm by finite rank operators.

First observe that the range of $T$ is separable and is contained in the closed span of a countable collection $\{y_{n} : n\in\mathbb{N} \}$ of elements of $\ell^{p}(I)$. Each such element vanishes on all but a countable number of values of $I$, so the set $J := \{i\in I : y_{n}(i) \neq 0 \text{ for some $n\in \mathbb{N}$} \}$ is countable. By continuity it follows that the range of $T$ is contained in $Y := \{x \in \ell^{p}(I) : x(i) = 0 \text{ for all $i\in I\setminus J$} \}$. If $J$ is finite then $T$ is a finite rank operator. Otherwise, as will be assumed from this point on, if $J$ is countably infinite then $Y$ is isometrically isomorphic to $\ell^{p}(J)$ which is isometrically isomorphic to $\ell^{p}$. Since $\ell^{p}$ has a Schauder basis, the isometric isomorphism induces a Schauder basis on $Y$.
Let $(P_{n})_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ be a sequence of finite rank projections associated with a Schauder basis for $Y$. Let $M>0$ such that $\|P_{n}\|_{\mathcal{B}(Y)} \leq M$ for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$. Define $B_{X} := \{x\in \ell^{p}(I) : \|x\|_{X} \leq 1 \}$. Since $T$ is compact one has that $T(B_{X})$ is totally bounded in $Y$. Hence given $\varepsilon > 0$ there exists a finite set $\mathcal{F}$ and a finite collection $\{y_{i} \in Y : i \in \mathcal{F} \}$ such that $T(B_{X}) \subseteq \bigcup_{i\in \mathcal{F} } \{y\in Y : \|y - y_{i}\|_{Y} < \varepsilon \}$. As $\lim_{n\to\infty} P_{n}y = y$ for each $y\in Y$ there is some $n_{0}\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $\|P_{n_{0}}y_{i} - y_{i} \|_{Y} < \varepsilon$ for all $i\in\mathcal{F}$. Define $P \in \mathcal{B}(X, \ell^{p}(I))$ by $Px := P_{n_{0}}Tx$. Then $P$ is a finite rank operator because $P_{n_{0}}$ is a finite rank operator. Let $x\in B_{X}$. Choose $i_{0} \in \mathcal{F}$ such that $\|Tx - y_{i_{0}} \|_{Y} < \varepsilon$. Then one has
\begin{align*}
\|P_{n_{0}}Tx - Tx \|_{Y} &\leq \|P_{n_{0}}(Tx - y_{i_{0}}) \|_{Y} + \|P_{n_{0}}y_{i_{0}} - y_{i_{0}} \|_{Y} + \|y_{i_{0}} - Tx\|_{Y} \\
&\leq M\varepsilon + \varepsilon + \varepsilon = (M+2) \varepsilon .
\end{align*}
Consequently $\|P - T\|_{\mathcal{B}(X,\ell^{p}(I) )} \leq (M+2)\varepsilon$ and the result follows.
